# Get Elasticsearch Config File Correctly Encoded

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How can I use the Elasticsearch Java API to get an index's configuration in json format, correctly encoded?

I have tried querying the admin.indices client with a GetMappingRequest. However the format of the mapping always has weird characters - I have tried ISO8559, ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16:

```
val bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
client.admin.indices.getMappings(new GetMappingsRequest()).get.writeTo(new OutputStreamStreamOutput(bs))
val mapping = new String(bs.toByteArray, CharSet.UTF8)
println(mapping)
```

Response:

```
{"_all@enabled":false},"_tt�tru�ype@1
index":"no" .   properties@valu`$�,"string",�4}}}dateOptionalTimeoffers42c9e293decoratedOfferd
```